# Exposing Docker-MySQL container on Azure to be used as DBaaS

Tags: mysql, azure, docker

I want to make specifically a docker container that holds standard Docker Hub MySQL image.

Once this container is deployed using Azure Container services, how do I use it remotely?

I want to connect to this (container-hosted) mysql server remotely, so that my APIs can upload data to this database over internet.

Where do I find host,username, password for this hosted MySQL db?

Comment: the username, password, database are controlled by its instigation [environment variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql). Its not recommended to expose MySQL database to the internet.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it sovle your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Once this container is deployed using Azure Container services, how do
> I use it remotely?

If you deploy the container to Azure Container Service, you can use a service with the `LoadBalancer` type to expose the port of the container to access outside.

> Where do I find host,username, password for this hosted MySQL db?

You can use the [environment variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) to set the user and password. Except this, you can connect into the container, then go inside the MySQL and create the users manually.